# foreach GetEnumerator error when converting to Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms-view-engine

I'm currently in the process of converting the MVC 2 portion of a hybrid Web Forms/MVC 2 application to MVC 3 (I'm not familiar with Web Forms or MVC 2) and have been encountering some problems with some of the foreach statements (which work fine in the original hybrid application).

When converting to Razor, some (not all) of my foreach statements will say something along the lines of:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Project.Activity.PortalMember>'
>   because
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Project.Activity.PortalMember>'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

This is an example .ascx from the Web Forms/MVC 2 application where the foreach works fine:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Project.Activity.PortalGroup>" %>
<% if (Model.PortalMembers.Count() > 0) {  %>
    <div>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.PortalMembers) {  %>
        <div>
            <%: item.SubAccount.FirstName %> <%: item.SubAccount.LastName %>
        </div>
    <%} %>
    </div>
<%} %>
```

This is my attempt for the .cshtml conversion that is giving me the error:

```
@model Project.Activity.PortalGroup

@if (Model.PortalMembers.Count() > 0) 
{
    <div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.PortalMembers) 
    {
        <div>
            @item.SubAccount.FirstName @item.SubAccount.LastName
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try add reference to System.Data.Linq.dll in your project

Comment: I've added the namespace to the webconfig in my Views folder, but the error seems to persist.

Comment: Try to add "@using System.Data.Linq" at the top of your view.

Comment: did you add the reference to the project itself? worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reference to System.Data.Entity.

Comment: Without a demonstration of how to do so this is just a comment, not an answer.